# Align center with respect to one of two containers

Tags: css, alignment

I have a container which has height of `100vh` in order to stretch for the entire screen. Inside that I have a `h1` and a `div`, i.e. two containers. Now, the content inside the `div` is what I want to center align on the page, but due to my `h1` I can't.

So basically the setup is:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <h1>This is a headline</h1>
    <div class="content-container">
         <p>Different stuff in here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS could look like:

```
.main-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And again, this would result in the two elements `h1` and `content-container` being centered together. But what I want to do is to center with respect to the `main-container` so that is always in the middle, and the `h1` is always some amount of pixels above. Is the only option to put the `h1` tag inside the `main-container`, and make it absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. h1 should be absolute position.
So, the best practice will be to move h1 inside the content-container, so that you can adjust the h1 position according to the content-container.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: absolute`, or you can perform some transform translate property such as `transform: translateY(20px)`